# Survey on Compared Running Time: Ellipsoid Method vs. Simplex Method

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization, combinatorial-optimization

If you look through papers on the Ellipsoid Method, there is a large agreement, that the Ellipsoid Method, although theoretically polynomial, is in practice way slower than the Simplex Method. Apparently, I was not able to find a single article that really backs up this claim by a survey, a meta-survey, some instances or anything else.
Does anybody have such a paper at hand that really shows the practical superiority of the Simplex Method?

Comment: the existence of http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/ should be a pretty strong argument; let me see if I can dig up an actual so-called "survey" :-) --- see also the nice article by M. Todd: http://cowles.econ.yale.edu/lec-lun/2001/todd-011024.pdf

Comment: People DO use interior point methods a lot. My understanding was that the ellipsoid method per se is viewed as a relatively inefficient realization of the interior point idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not a survey. Nevertheless, [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016754198490019X) can be interesting as we can read in the abstract:

“The computer experiment compared the two algorithms performance in solving SX exponential time problems. This represented a best possible case (for KA) and a worst possible case (for SX).”

KA - Khachian's algorithm
SX – simplex algorithm.

Unfortunately, I don’t have access to a copy of this paper.

Comment: This seems to be a paper that does exactly what I want, so thank you for the answer. But apparently this paper seems to be from 1984 and there has been quite some progress in the field, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the 2011 book,
*Interior Point Algorithms: Theory and Analysis*,
by Yinyu Ye.
(Vol. 44. John Wiley & Sons, 2011. [Google Books link](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=9Jh58LImo-UC&oi=fnd&pg=PR7&dq=Interior%20Point%20Algorithms:%20Theory%20and%20Analysis%20&ots=Bn0OJVFDaQ&sig=GduncD7FJFVFR2cb5xs5nQzkmEM#v=onepage&q=Interior%20Point%20Algorithms:%20Theory%20and%20Analysis&f=false).)
Here is a snippet from the Preface:

---

[image: Ye Pref]

---

Comment: This book was actually first published in 1997. And [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.111.4071&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is a 1996 preprint.